# Most widespread use of PGP after 20 years

Tags: cryptography, encryption, digital-signature, pgp

Phil Zimmerman released [PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) on June 5, 1991](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).  As we examine the legacy of that far-sighted and brave act 20 years later, what are the most widespread and helpful uses of PGP signatures, and of PGP encryption?

See also:

- [Why I Wrote PGP - Phil Zimmerman](http://www.philzimmermann.com/EN/essays/WhyIWrotePGP.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PGP signatures are used to sign software packages in some Linux distributions, including [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) and [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/). This is quite widespread, although most Linux users are never aware of it.

PGP encryption, for what is was meant initially (i.e. emails), is commonly used in commercial situations, where some parties wish to exchange work documents. PGP keys are thus exchanged directly, not using the certificates (keys signed by other people) and the "web of trust". I often do it with customers. PGP benefits from very good integration and simple usage in many mailer softwares. PGP signatures are also used there, as an integrity check (but not in their "non-repudiation" role).

To sum up, the one feature of PGP which is almost never used is the web of trust.

Comment: You say *"the one feature of PGP which is almost never used is the web of trust."* - What exactly do you mean by "used", and what evidence do you have for that?  I note that there are over 100,000 signatures of one user's key/certificate by another user that constitute the web of trust.  How does that compare with other uses?  You can see a fascinating and beautiful analysis of the web of trust here, the structures of which suggest some significant uses: [Wotsap: Dissecting the Leaf of Trust](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~jc/wotsap/leafoftrust.html)

Comment: @nealmcb: I mean that I have never encountered any situation where the WoT was actually used to ascertain whether a given public key was genuine. I _have_ seen many people signing each other's keys, under the assumption that this was "the right thing to do" and that it would allow some potential WoT-based certification; but when it comes to actually sending encrypted emails, you send them to people you know, for which the WoT has little added value.

Comment: @ Thomas: Signatures are great! I find myself needing GPG for sharing emails and files (during incidents with other security professionals who rely on GPG), but would prefer S/MIME. I think other security professionals should move to S/MIME and leave GPG for signing installables/packages

Comment: I agree with @atdre... "PGP benefits from very good integration and simple usage in many mailer softwares", and very *bad* integration in some other mail software...

Answer (score 6):

For almost all communications between me and many of my global banking clients, PGP is the trust layer which allows us to pass very sensitive data to each other. Most of these clients run a PGP gateway which ensures all comms to me from them is encrypted (thus avoiding accidental cleartext emails) and allows for an escrow in order that the organisation can check for viruses, information leakage etc.

The ones without PGP Universal all use pgp or gpg desktop clients - either way, we validate pgp keys out of band and gain a strong assurance that our emails are secured between us, time stamped and signed.

Absolutely invaluable for comms about security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Retroshare is an acentered P2P/Friend2Friend network software using GPG primarily as a authentication mecanism, and use its own kind of web of trust way to add people to "your ring" which is primarily a contact list.
They use the PGP signature if you want to sign some content on the Retroshare forum or you can just post anonymously.
I don't know if they use it for actually transferring data, because I think they use more their Turtle transfer protocol which is some kind of anonymous VPN so you don't really know where the data comes from.

Personnaly, I don't use it that much because I'm really used to webmails. But that's something I'm looking forward to using more.
My other usage of PGP is for signing package for ubuntu, and that's it. I don't have a lot of contacts using it

Comment: Note that RetroShare might have some security issues http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2016/09/retroshare-scandal-of-free-communication.html